# How to check if users exist in DataBase

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

with below code, i am able to pull the data however my script (If and else ) is not working please advice the  some tips

```
server.post('/like', (req, res,next) => {
    var Mobile = req.body.rPhone;
    // Get checkout pending users data
    const query3 = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('Phone', '=', Mobile).filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
    datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
        const tasks = results[0];
        var newData = JSON.stringify(tasks);
        const parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
        const visitor = parsed;
        const PhoneN = visitor[0].Phone;
        const OutTime = visitor[0].OutTime;

        console.log(PhoneN, OutTime), function(err, Mobile){
            var Mobile = req.body.rPhone;
            var Nodata = 'null';
            console.log(Mobile)
            if (err) { 
                console.log("Not Regsitered user")
            } else if (Mobile === PhoneN && OutTime === Nodata) {
                Console.log("You have not Logged Out")
            } else {
                Console.log("Do something")
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the function `function(err, Mobile)`is not executed at all. You are just defining an anonymous function, that is neither stored anywhere nor called directly.

Comment: What is the best way ...? can you please share some example

Answer (score 0):

There is some variable name issue in your code.

```
var Mobile = req.body.rPhone;
// Get checkout pending users data
const query = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('Phone', '=', Mobile).filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
datastore.runQuery(query)
```

Comment: query function is working fine, IF and Else Condition is not working

Comment: Query output - if records found 
 [ { Host: 'Rajpal',
  OutTime: 'null',
 VID: 'Kir81083180',
 Phone: '8108288888',
 snap:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/18/18/56/user-3331256_960_720.png',
Purpose: 'Interview', 
FName: 'Kiran',
INtime: '12:46:28 PM',
Date: 'Wed Jul 31 2019',
Email: 'abc@abc.com',
Business: 'TCPL',
LName: 'Setty',
[Symbol(KEY)]:
Key {
namespace: undefined,
name: 'Kir81083180',
kind: 'VData',
path: [Getter] } } ]

Comment: I think err is creating the problem (datastore.runQuery(query).then((err, results) => )

Answer (score 0):

```
server.post('/like', (req, res,next) => {
var Mobile = req.body.rPhone;
// Get checkout pending users data
const query3 = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('Phone', '=', Mobile).filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
datastore.runQuery(query).then((err, results) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("Some error", err);
    }
    if(!results.length){
        console.log("Not Regsitered user")
    }
    const tasks = results[0];
    var newData = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    const parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
    const visitor = parsed;
    const PhoneN = visitor[0].Phone;
    const OutTime = visitor[0].OutTime;

    console.log(PhoneN, OutTime);

    var Nodata = 'null';
    console.log(Mobile);
    if (Mobile === PhoneN && OutTime === Nodata) {
         console.log("You have not Logged Out")
    } else {
         console.log("Do something")
    }
});
})
```

Try this code. That function is anonymous and you are not calling from anywhere.

Comment: Err- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: if( !results || !results.length){
        console.log("Not Regsitered user")
    }

Comment: Thanks - getting error -"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: I have attached DB image and query is -const query = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('Phone', '=', Mobile);

Comment: const query3 = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('Phone', '=', Mobile).filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');

Comment: I mean what your runQuery does. Please explain
or just console the "results" and write code accordingly

Comment: Query output - if records found 
 [ { Host: 'Rajpal',
  OutTime: 'null',
 VID: 'Kir81083180',
 Phone: '8108288888',
 snap:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/18/18/56/user-3331256_960_720.png',
Purpose: 'Interview', 
FName: 'Kiran',
INtime: '12:46:28 PM',
Date: 'Wed Jul 31 2019',
Email: 'abc@abc.com',
Business: 'TCPL',
LName: 'Setty',
[Symbol(KEY)]:
Key {
namespace: undefined,
name: 'Kir81083180',
kind: 'VData',
path: [Getter] } } ]